# Use svg file in openlayer to represent a layer

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer

I want to use an SVG file as a source for one of the layers for my map in OpenLayers. The svg file is in a coordinate system such that it overlays my coordinate system of my map. I have tried the code below but it gives me

> AssertionError "Assertion failed. See
>   https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.3/doc/errors/#7 for details.

```
let Tunnel = new vectorLayer({
          source: new VectorSource({
            projection: projection2326,
            url: 'assets/Tunnel.svg',
            wrapX: false
          }),
          extent: [813967.0186951972, 825986.8061076261,814705.0826232458, 817842.6498878849]
        });



 this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map-container',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM({ 
          wrapX: false
        })
      }), Tunnel
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: projection2326,
        center: getCenter(extent),
        zoom:13,
      })
    });
```

Comment: Correct address for error code desciption is https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/errors/#7. Error desciption says: `format` must be set when `url` is set.

Comment: I do not understand what this means ?

Comment: See docs for `VectorSource`: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html

Comment: I have seen it, I tried adding  format: new FeatureFormat({
              dataProjection: projection2326,
              featureProjection: projection2326
            }),

Comment: gives me another error which is "core.js:7187 ERROR Error: Unimplemented abstract method."

Comment: If you look at format docs https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_Feature-FeatureFormat.html, you will se there is no option for SVG. This means that SVG cannot be `VectorSource`, you have to declare it as `ImageLayer`. See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html